# Can't enable Ralink RT2561/RT61 wireless card

Tags: 11.04, server, wireless, command-line, ralink

I have been reading various other posts on the matter but none of the solutions are working so I thought I might as well ask.

Just installed Ubuntu Server 11.04 on my old Dell Optiplex 330. It has a wireless PCI card installed that I bought for it's compatibility with Ubuntu 10. It was working on Ubuntu 10 prior to the new install.

After the install there were no lights on the card and I can not use it.

When running;
sudo lshw -C network

the device is listed but labelled Disabled.

The card is a Ralink corp, RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI

This is a headless install so command line help only please.

Thanks in advance!

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM5787 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1d:09:1e:89:5f
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.119 duplex=full firmware=5787-v3.23 ip=192.168.0.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:44 memory:dcff0000-dcffffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:03:02.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:1f:1f:8f:eb:e6
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt61pci driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic-pae firmware=N/A latency=64 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:18 memory:dcef8000-dcefffff
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Comment: What is the output from: **sudo lshw -C network** and  **iwconfig**?  I am using that WiFi chipset, but in an external device.

Comment: @david6 Added to original post! Sorry for the delay! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The *Ralink Technology* cards, and specifically **RT2561/RT61**, have compatibility issues with later drivers (developed for later cards).

see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/665364/

Your best bet is to try **blacklisting** the later drivers, which will stop them trying to control the card (and failing).  The only *other alternative* is to compile your own driver.

see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10829039&postcount=10

Otherwise: (not good news)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9842725

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10926618

etc.

**SUPPORT PAGE:**

(Ralink, Linux drivers)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10926618&postcount=1

Comment: Thanks! I shall try tonight and let you know how it goes.